# Can hex format be used with JSON files? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, json

The following object is a valid one in plain Javascript. However, if the same is added to a JSON file, the file does not pass validation. Why is that?

```
var message = {
    "senderID": [ 0x01 ],
    "receiverID": [ 0xFF ],
    "commandCode": [ 0x00, 0x05 ],
    "payload": [ 0xFF ]
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

JSON does not support hexadecimal numbers but they are supported in JSON5.
[json5.org](https://json5.org/)

Comment: Note that JSON5 is not the 5th iteration of JSON; rather, it's a separate specification altogether that builds on the ideas of JSON. In other words, don't get confused between "JSON didn't support hexadecimal X years ago, but it does now" and "there are other data format specifications that are similar to JSON and also support hexadecimal."

Comment: The OP is more comfortable in hex, so perhaps you should have written `... didn't support hexadecimal 0xX years ago...`

Answer (score 31):

The JSON spec supports *numbers* as values but explicitly does not support octal or hexidecimal. This is in part to increase interchange between languages. You could just as easily represent `0xFF` as a string, `"0xFF"` and parse that out when using it.

---

From [json.org](http://www.json.org/):

> A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal and hexadecimal formats are not used.

According to the [ECMA-404, 2nd edition, December 2017](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf):

> A number is a sequence of decimal digits with no superfluous leading zero. It may have a preceding minus
> sign (U+002D). It may have a fractional part prefixed by a decimal point (U+002E). It may have an exponent,
> prefixed by e (U+0065) or E (U+0045) and optionally + (U+002B) or – (U+002D). The digits are the code
> points U+0030 through U+0039.

The spec also explains why this is restriction is beneficial to both producer and consumer:

> JSON is agnostic about the semantics of numbers. In any programming language, there can be a variety of number types of various capacities and complements, fixed or floating, binary or decimal. That can make interchange between different programming languages difficult. JSON instead offers only the representation of numbers that humans use: a sequence of digits. All programming languages know how to make sense of digit sequences even if they disagree on internal representations. That is enough to allow interchange.

Comment: How not supporting hexadecimal increases interchange between languages?

Comment: @Ivella I've updated my answer with the explanation from the spec.

Comment: I think not supporting integers with hexadecimal syntax (e.g. `{ foo: 0x1234 }`) is just a historical mishap. There would be zero disagreements what value such an integer represents (it's literally same as `4660`) but the conversion from internal representation to hex and back would be much faster than base-10 numbers we currently have to use. As a result, JSON generating code must do repeated divisions to export the internally used numbers instead of using 16 byte lookup table for each digit. For floating point numbers, I agree that not supporting hex representation was the correct choice.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Though I agree the hex format is pretty indisputably clear, one could also argue that JSON is designed to be simple and lightweight, and even if hexadecimal numbers would be efficient/easy/smart/a good idea, they bog down the spec with extra information.

Comment: @nullromo: sure, spec design is always a compromise but supporting at least one integer format that doesn't require doing divisions and multiplications to convert from serialized to binary format would have been important if you want to make JSON usable for high performance use cases. Other than this mishap / missing feature, rest of the format could have been used for high performance data transfers, too. Hex format would have had lower bandwidth requirements and have practically zero CPU overhead compared to base-10 numbers we now have.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen this isn't a mishap. Look at a hexadecimal number like 0xFFFFFFFF, which you might think is 4294967295, but it could also be -1 (a uint32_t or an int32_t), and that is only if the operating system is a 32-bit system. What happens on a 64-bit system, or a 16-bit system? Big-endian or little-endian? This is what they mean with "internal representations". The decimal format is unambiguous. Yes, it requires some overhead to convert into the internal representation, but it keeps the JSON string agnostic and human readable without having to specify the exact number formatting.

Comment: I'd argue that `0xFFFFFFFF` is always 4294967295 and if you want to represent -1 in hex, you should write `-0x01`. Yes, it's different from how CPUs internally work but doesn't encode any endianess in the interchange format and it's still really fast to implement.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen 0xFFFFFFFF will only be -1 when storing as an a signed long. In this case 4294967295 would be -1 as well. '0xFFFFFFFF' and '4294967295' don't just simply represent the same numerical value as a variable, they have the same exact value in memory (11111111111111111111111111111111) regardless of system, assuming it can handle 32 bit values. They literally represent the same value regardless of system, language, etc.

Comment: JSON shouldn't assume 32 bit CPU with two's complement binary system and as such, 0xFFFFFFFF should be interpreted to mean hexadecimal representation of integer 4294967295. You can perfectly well put the sign in front of the hexadecimal representation to transmit data about negative numbers and it's up to the receiving system to use 64 bit internal representation for computations if required by the underlying architecture to represent (negative) integer -4294967295.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen `with hexadecimal syntax (e.g. { foo: 0x1234 })` LOL, actually NOT. Only *one-byte sized chunks* are kinda sorta of disagreements-free as most of  modern computers coalesced on 8-bits byte (but if you would read early RFCs you would find that byte was from 5 to 9 bits on different computers, and internet protocols used to acknowledge that. And if we would look outside USA then not even all computers were binary in 1970-s). *Your very example* luckily shows why not to hex out BLOBs: on different computers it would be equal to `{ foo: [0x12, 0x34] }` or `{ foo: [0x34, 0x12] }`

Comment: @Arioch'The There's no disagreement what number 0x1234 is. You're correct that there is no agreement how that number is represented natively in RAM but that kind of agreement is not needed for JSON. JSON should be about transmitting numbers, not memory contents. Similarly 0xFFFF is always 65535 (base 10) but sometimes *memory* contents [0xFF, 0xFF] might be -1 if *interpreted* as 16 bit two complement's memory storage. JSON != memory.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen except for transmitting BLOBs (and hex numbers today being de-facto standard for watching memory dumps) why would JSON have hex-numbers at all? You you look at the original question you would clearly see byte-split binary dumps in it, kind of XML CDATA

Comment: So... JSON is *not* "agnostic about the semantics of numbers", then. The spec writers simply misunderstood numbers, and somehow thought that a sequence of digits implies decimal. Try telling that to the Sumerians. The whole quoted paragraph is nonsense.